# How can i get specific part of string?

Tags: iphone, nsstring, split

I have a string like:

```
"This is test string http://www.google.com and it is working."
```

I want to get only the link (`http://www.google.com`) from above string. How can I get it?

Comment: What is the difference between 'h t t p://www.google.com' and 'h t t p://www.google.com'? You have posted the same string....

Comment: and where is the whole string?

Comment: "This is test string http:www.google.com and it is working" is a whole string

Comment: All the URLs that you are going to grab end in ".com"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work like a CHARM:

```
NSString *totalString = @"This is test string http://www.google.com and it is working.";
NSLog(@"%@", totalString);

NSRange urlStart = [totalString rangeOfString: @"http"];
NSRange urlEnd = [totalString rangeOfString: @".com"];
NSRange resultedMatch = NSMakeRange(urlStart.location, urlEnd.location - urlStart.location + urlEnd.length);

NSString *linkString = [totalString substringWithRange:resultedMatch];

NSLog (@"%@", linkString);
```

Comment: Thnx my frnd it is working perfectly :-)

Comment: Be awared! your URLs must start with "http" and end in ".com", if they end in ".net" or ".info" or whatever, edit NSRange urlEnd.

Answer (score 1):

It should work like this:

```
NSString *test = @"This is test string http://www.google.com and it is working.";

NSString *string = [test stringByAppendingString:@" "];

NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"https?://[^ ]* "
                                                                       options:0
                                                                         error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
    NSRange matchRange = [match range];
    NSString *url = [string substringWithRange:matchRange];

    NSLog(@"Found URL: %@", url);
}
```

You can find further information about using NSRegularExpression here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the NSString class documentation - there are a bunch of methods on there to find the location of certain substring formats, split strings on delimeters, and extract substrings etc.

e.g. in the example above if you wanted to extract any embedded url in a string you could first split the string up using:

```
NSArray *substrings = [myString componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

then in the resultant array, loop through it and find out if it has a 'http' string:

```
for (int i=0;i<[substrings length];i++) {
   NSString aStr = [substrings objectAtIndex:i];
   if ([aStr rangeOfString:@"http"].location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"I found a http url:%@", aStr);
   }
}
```

Comment: [substrings count]  have you actually ever written a line of code yourself?